# No database selected when using INSERT in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics-api

Okay I'm quite new to php and mysql and I can't seem to figure this out. So what I'm trying to do is send some variables to a MySQL table. I have set up the connection inside a function (I believe this is possible(?) )

And with my current code it gives me the following error.

> Notice: No database selected in INSERT INTO retrieveddata (profileId, profileName, pageViews, profileRevenue, currentDate) VALUES(NULL,'www.mywebsite.nl[testview2]', '48702', '0.0',NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\analyticsoverview\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 281

I have tried adding the select_db to my code but it doesn't work.
This is my code.

```
    function printResults(&$results) {

        if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];
        $pageviews = $rows[0][1];
        $bounces = $rows [0][2];
        $betaalgoal = $rows [0][3];
        $transrevenue = $rows [0][4];


// set up database connection


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "googleanalytics";

// Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }    

// select database that needs to be filled with the data from the variables

    $conn->select_db('googleanalytics');

// the mysql query to insert the variables into table called retrieveddata
<
    $query    = "INSERT INTO retrieveddata (profileId, profileName, pageViews, profileRevenue, currentDate) 
         VALUES(NULL,'$profileName', '$pageviews', '$transrevenue',NULL)";
    mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
```

Comment: You already selected the DB in `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` so why use `$conn->select_db('googleanalytics');`? Plus, you're mixing MySQL functions using `mysql_*`, so your entire code is failing you, *twice*.

Comment: @Fred ii. Correct and please go through what he suggested to you. thumbs up

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I should have just posted that as an answer, however sometimes they come back and say: *"It still doesn't work"* - You know the drill ;-)

Comment: ha ha ha . yes i understand that.:):) happens often to you. isn't it?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Not to mention 281 lines; *wow*. yeah, I'll pass on this one. OP's got enough now to test it out.

Comment: Yup. you are right. but sometime what i feel that your language goes beyond OP's thinking. that's why they didn't get your suggestions. it's my personal feeling. But you are correct always as much as i saw your comments and answers.

Comment: thanks for the fast replies! will test some stuff out now :)

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I changed my mind, since someone posted an answer and still mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: @ampyfibe consult my answer below, if you haven't already. Unless you wish to stay on with the other person's answer, the choice is yours.

Comment: @fred -ii- Thanks for your reply and answer fred I will test this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need `$conn->select_db('googleanalytics');`

You already chose your database in:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Then, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_` functions that do not intermix with any other functions.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO retrieveddata 
          (profileId, profileName, pageViews, profileRevenue, currentDate) 
         VALUES (NULL,'$profileName', '$pageviews', '$transrevenue',NULL)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if ( !$result ) {
trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Pass the database connection to the query and for the error trigger which I changed.

Or simply, `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

**Sidenote:**

Now, if your data contains apostrophes or other data the MySQL may complain about, you will need to sanitize your data using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Otherwise, you may get syntax errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

I.e. and as an example:

```
$profileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $profileName);
```

and doing the same for the other variables.

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Currently gives me Fatal error: query failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\analyticsoverview\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 289. But I'll still have some other options to try. I'll let you know how it goes ;).

Comment: @ampyfibe You'll need to find out exactly what the real error is. Use `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` if you are not doing that already and check your logs. Just a `query failed` isn't enough to find out why the query failed.

Comment: @ampyfibe also add error reporting, as stated near the bottom of my answer. See if that also helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete

```
$conn->select_db('googleanalytics');
```

because when you create the connection you've already selected the database, it's the last parameter of mysqli().

Try to change:

```
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
```

whith this:

```
$conn->query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
```

When you build your query you have to concatenate more strings, elsewhere your variables won't be correctly used

```
$query="INSERT INTO retrieveddata (profileId, profileName, pageViews, profileRevenue, currentDate) VALUES(NULL,'".$profileName."', '".$pageviews."', '".$transrevenue."',NULL)";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have done what you said now it gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\analyticsoverview\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 284

Comment: `or trigger_error(mysql_error()` are you sure about that?

Comment: @zanna line 284:     mysqli->query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten a thing, the correct line is 
$conn->query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);

Comment: Replaced it with the correct line and currently gives me:
Notice: in INSERT INTO retrieveddata (profileId, profileName, pageViews, profileOmzet, currentDate) VALUES(NULL,'www.mywebsite.nl[testview2]', '48702', '0.0',NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\analyticsoverview\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 284

Comment: I've appended the correction of the query building, times ago I've got the same error and I solved it in that way